# Asp .net mvc Show function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp .net mvc project in which I have a show function to show the details for a specific ID called TicketID. TicketID is posted to the C# function using Ajax correctly and we have it[function return is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh0zB.png) . but the result is null although we have the data in database.[database is not null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCPrq.png)

This is my Controller code:

```
TicketDetail public JsonResult ShowDetail(int TicketID) 
{ 
    var Result1 = DB.Tickets.Where(Item => Item.ID == TicketID).ToList(); 
    return Json(Result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you clarify? Are you saying Result1 is evaluating to NULL? (FYI - you'll probably get more responses if you show the code as text instead of linking to a picture.)

Comment: This is my Controller code
/
  #region TicketDetail
        public JsonResult ShowDetail(int TicketID)
        {

            var Result1 = DB.Tickets.Where(Item => Item.ID == TicketID).ToList();
            return Json(Result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        #endregion

Comment: And this is my js code 
/////
    //ShowDetail####-Start
    $scope.ShowDetail = function (ID) {
        var TicketID = ID;
        var getData = $http.get("/User/UserHome/ShowDetail?TicketID=" + TicketID)
        getData.then(function (VarMessage) {
            $scope.ListSingleTickets = VarMessage.data
        }, function () {
        });

        window.location.href = "/User/Tickets/TicketDetail"

    }

Comment: I made an edit to the post to show you how you can use formatting to make the code more readable. Code in the comment is really hard to read. If the js code is relevant, you may want to edit your question to include that.

When you say "result is null" - are you talking about Result1 is null, the return value of ShowDetail is null, or both?

Comment: @jefftrotman Can we have an anydesk session in which you could help me?
i'm running out of time